# How to retrieve filename on startup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to conditionally launch a user form when excel opens based on the file's name. However, I believe that the code is running before the file fully launches, giving me an error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim name As String
    name = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    If InStr(name, "Export Checksheet") > 0 Then
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Testing this on a file that's already open runs fine, but trying to let it run naturally as the file opens causes a Run-time error '91' and points me at the line defining the `name` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `ThisWorkbook` is loading *before* whatever other workbook you're opening, so `ActiveWorkbook` is `Nothing` and any member call against it will raise error 91.

The `Workbook_Open` handler will only ever run for `ThisWorkbook` (the document that's hosting the VBA project) - what you need is to wire up another handler, at application level, so that you can run code whenever *any* workbook is opened.

Change your `Workbook_Open` handler to capture a reference to the `Application` instance into a module-level `WithEvents` object variable:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set app = Me.Application
End Sub
```

Now select `app` from the left-hand dropdown, and create a handler for the `WorkbookOpen` event - *that* is where you'll want to verify whether you need to pop up that dialog:

```
Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If InStr(Wb.FullName, "Export Checksheet") > 0 Then
        With New UserForm1
            .Show
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that the application-wide event *provides* you with the `Workook` object, so you don't need to care whether it's the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Don't fully understand that, but it worked. (though you forgot `ByVal` in `Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(Wb As Workbook)` which was causing a problem). Thanks!

Comment: @Tock Press F2 to bring up the *Object Browser*, then look for the `Application` class under the `Excel` library: you'll see a bunch of members have a little lightning bolt icon - these are *events* exposed at the `Application` level, and with a `WithEvents app As Excel.Application` object you can handle any of them. Now browse again and look for the `Workbook` class members - you'll see one of its events is the `Open` event: when you have a `Workbook_Open` procedure in a `Workbook` module, that's the event you're handling, and when you're in a `Workbook` module you can handle any of them too!

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.name Like "*Export Checksheet*" Then
            wb.Activate
            Userform1.Show
        End If
    Next wb

End Sub
```

Though I don't get why do you do this, why don't you write this code and the userform only on the workbook Export checksheet?

Comment: Don't you need to add in the pattern options for this to work? e.g. `If ThisWorkbook.name Like "*Export Checksheet*" Then`

Comment: Yeah @Tom totally forgot about the `*`, edited the answer.

Comment: The code's used in multiple workbooks that are sent to us using a template and (typically) contain this in the title. As a result we have to drop this code in personal.xlsb which makes `ThisWorkbook` return the title of personal.xlsb instead of the active workbook.

Comment: The code `Workbook_Open` triggers when you open a workbook... So the `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` will be the same (excel focuses on the new workbook). To find out if you really have the workbook you need I'd do a loop through all the workbooks and check if any of them is the one you need. But not on the `Workboook_Open` event but a normal macro in a button.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. The code's being run from personal.xlsb and not from the workbook we're actually editting, so ThisWorkbook returns information regarding THAT workbook, and not regarding the active one. I've verified this several times because being able to use ThisWorkbook would solve my problem. Should the code be run from the same workbook, then yes they'd return the same value.

Comment: I agree with you on the last part, but `Workbook_Open` will trigger ONLY when you open your personal.xlsb, when you open another workbook nothing will happen. That's what I mean.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` will ALWAYS only ever refer to the document that's hosting the VBA project.

Comment: personal.xlsb is automatically run alongside any other excel document that is opened. Since it's being opened with every workbook, `Workbook_Open` in personal.xlsb will run whenever you open any excel file.

Comment: @Tock I've written and used Excel add-ins, but I'm not familiar with personal.xlsb mechanics. Clearly however, `ActiveWorkbook` is `Nothing` when it runs, and `ThisWorkbook` is the wrong object, so another approach is in order.

Comment: Ooooook now, as Mathieu I had no idea about that. Try my edit @Tock this should work.

Comment: Handling `WorkbookOpen` at application level seems a cleaner & safer approach, since it gives you a reference to the `Workbook` object being opened. The loop will show the form 3 times if 3 workbooks were already opened & matching the criteria, even when only 1 workbook was in the process of opening.