# Programmatically Add Buttons to Sheet on WorkbookOpen

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to load some buttons onto spreadsheets which include "Report" in the name using a script from a personal macro workbook. I've verified that the script is actually running with the MsgBox, and have also verified that the script successfully adds buttons when I manually execute it, however it's failing to load the buttons onto the sheet when the file is opened.

I've tried adding `Worksheets(1).Activate` as well as changing `ActiveSheet` to `Worksheets(1)` as I thought that maybe it's not working because the sheet wasn't active yet, but that didn't help.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application
Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    If InStr(wb.FullName, "Checksheet") > 0 Then
        'stuff happening
    ElseIf InStr(wb.FullName, "Report") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Good"
        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
        Dim btn As Button

        With Range("D2")
            Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
            With btn
                '.OnAction = "BtnTest.secondTest"
                .Caption = "Verify First Report"
                .name = "Btn1"
            End With
        End With

        With Range("D4")
            Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
            With btn
                '.OnAction = "BtnTest.secondTest"
                .Caption = "Verify Second Report"
                .name = "Btn2"
            End With
        End With

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set app = Me.Application
End Sub
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly: Opening files which include "Report" in their name should trigger the code, but those files should not contain any VBA code themselves? The relevant code should only be in your personal macro workbook?

Comment: Use `wb.Activesheet` or `wb.Worksheets(1)`

Comment: Correct. Everything is written in and executed from the macro workbook (making the event handler necessary - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56671540/8722088).

Comment: @Rory Oh jeez, it really was that easy. I even used that in the first `If` code block. Feel free to answer so I can credit you.

Comment: Verify `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name` and `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Parent.Name`? It's a good idea (a best practice, really) to [not rely on Activate/Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wb.Activesheet` or `wb.Worksheets(1)`

Your code is in the ThisWorkbook module so `Activesheet` is implicitly `ThisWorkbook.Activesheet` rather than `Application.Activesheet`